# Keras give less accuracy than any classifier

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, text-classification

I use python to multi-class text classification , my data set contains 25000 Arabic tweets divided into 10 classes[sport, politics,....]
When I use

```
training = pd.read_csv('E:\cluster data\One_File_nonnormalizenew2norm.txt', sep="*")
training.dropna(inplace=True)
training.columns = ["text", "class1"]
training['class1'] = training.class1.astype('category').cat.codes
training.dropna(inplace=True)
# create our training data from the tweets
text = training['text']

y = (training['class1'])

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
sentences_train, sentences_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(text, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=1000)
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer



vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit(sentences_train)

X_train = vectorizer.transform(sentences_train)
X_test  = vectorizer.transform(sentences_test)
X_train
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
score = classifier.score(X_test, y_test)

print("Accuracy:", score)
```

**Accuracy: 0.9525099601593625**

When I use keras:

```
model = Sequential()
max_words=5000
model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(input_dim,), activation='softmax'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='softmax'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='softmax'))
model.add(Dense(10))

model.summary()

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer='adam',
  metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train,  batch_size=150,  epochs=5,  verbose=1, validation_split=0.3,shuffle=True)


predicted = model.predict(X_test)
predicted = np.argmax(predicted, axis=1)
accuracy_score(y_test, predicted)
```

**0.28127490039840636**

where the mistake???

**update**
I change the code to:

```
model = Sequential()
max_words=5000
model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(input_dim,)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
#model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))####
model.add(Dense(10))

model.summary()
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer='adam',
  metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(X_train, y_train,batch_size=150,epochs=10,verbose=1,validation_split=0.3,shuffle=True)
predicted = model.predict(X_test)
predicted = np.argmax(predicted, axis=1)
accuracy_score(y_test, predicted)
```

0.7201593625498008
still bad accuracy!!!

Comment: softmax as activation in hidden layers makes no sense.

Comment: when i use Relu no changes occur??any advice?

Comment: I don't see where is the call to model.fit, are you actually training the model? Also softmax with one class won't work either.

Comment: are you `predicting` your model before `fit` your model?!!

Comment: Training and designing a neural network is not a matter of trial and error like you are doing, now you removed all activations, which also makes no sense. Please take a neural network book or tutorial and read it thorughtly, and look at code samples online (like Keras MNIST CNN). We won't solve a moving problem for you, you have to learn a lot to make a network work.

Comment: I remove all activation according to answer below!!!!

Comment: @ Matias Valdenegro
can you suggest to me  sample code or tutorial to apply keras in nlp

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas.

1. Remove all softmax activations (as @Matias said).
2. Remove the `model.add(Dense(1,activation='softmax'))`, it's probably destroying your results.
3. Do more than 5 epochs.
4. You are not using the same tweets for validation in the two approaches.

You should probably give the accuracy on both the training and the testing datasets to be sure what is going on.

Comment: Can a tweet be in two classes or just one? If just one, put "softmax" in the last layer. And 50 epochs is always better than 10!

Comment: only one class .
OK i will try 50 epochs